# How can I specify a one-argument constructor using Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

Using Lombok, is it possible to specify a one-argument constructor?

My intention is to use Lombok annotations to create a constructor such as the one below.

```
class MyClass {
    private String param;
    private Integer count;

    public MyClass(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes what's the issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I didn't find in documentation

Use this: http://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

You have to initialize all variables which should not be part of the constructor.

> @RequiredArgsConstructor generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field that requires special handling. All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared. For those fields marked with @NonNull, an explicit null check is also generated.

So the following should create an one argument (`param`) constructor:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor class MyClass {
     private String param;
     private Integer count = -1;
}
```

Comment: But I don't need to set `Integer count` with constructor. So @RequiredArgsConstructor is not my case.

Comment: I made an edit. I don't have lombock running, so what does it generates?

Comment: @KnutKnutsen "RequiredArgsConstructor" only for final fields.

Answer (score 30):

Lombok doesn't let you to specify the fields exactly, but there are 3 annotations to choose from. With

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor class MyClass {
    private final String param;
    private Integer count;
}
```

you can get it. An argument is *required* if it's not initialized inline and `final` or `@NonNull`.

Comment: for all those who might have missed it, It is NonNull (a custom lombok annotation) and not the famous @NotNull. I wish they switch using NotNull instead

Answer (score 20):

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@NonNull` are two important keys to solve the problem above. Because `@RequiredArgsConstructor` creates a constructor with fields which are annotated by `@NonNull` annotation.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyClass {
    @NonNull
    private String param;
    private Integer count;
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```java
class MyClass {
    private String param;
    private Integer count;

    public MyClass(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```